# Fail if primary-key not present with plain SQL

Tags: sql, primary-key

Let says we want to find products by category.

```
select * from product p where p.category in ('cat1', 'cat2')
```

This SQL would return 0 rows if there is no products in cat1 or cat2 and unfortunately also if cat1 and cat2 is misspelled. I would like to get a SQL exception if these categories doesn't exists.

Illustrated here with pseudo code, notice the use of **guaranteed**

```
select * from product p where p.category in 
(select c.id from category c where c.id guaranteed in ('cat1', 'cat2'))
```

or with a join instead of sub select. Primary key is now a number which just as easily could be wrong

```
select p.* from product p 
inner join category c on c.id = p.category
where c.id guaranteed in (56, 234)
```

If not in plain SQL, does Oracle or SQL server have this feature?

Comment: In your sample, category is a column of product table. So how could you make a distinction between "not exists" (misspelled) and "no product with that category" : if there's no product with that category, than it means the category doesn't exist.

Comment: Why do you need a SQL exception?   What would that tell you that 0 rows does not?

Comment: Raphaël Althaus > A category could exists with no products attached.

Comment: Blam>> The exception would tell me I am trying to use a category that does not exists.

Comment: Yes stig, sub-selects are supported by Oracle SQL Server and MySQL too.

Comment: Just check categories presence with one 'plain' SQL query and query data with another. I hope you have some application behind these queries?

Comment: Arvo >> Spot on, that is the problem. There is no application that could fire an extra SQL doing this check. This is used in reporting and the business people is writing these SQLs. I want to help them writing correct reports.

Comment: If you're trying to insert a row into a subtable and make sure that row uses a valid category (and throw an error if not), then use a foreign key constraint on the subtable.

Comment: Duston >> The question is only regarding select